# Should I sent images through JSON

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, backend

I'm new to Django, and I'm building a REST backend for my iOS app, I figured out encode an Image to it's Base64 data, and I would like to use it together with some texts, is it a good idea to put it into the JSON for the rest of the data or is it better to use another request to download each image data.

I'm guessing that *separating concerns* is the best way, and have two GET request to retrieve the data, but I just want to be sure!.

OPTION A

```
{
"owner": {
    "username": "lilysmith",
    "email": "lily@email.com",
    "first_name": "Lily",
    "last_name": "Smith"
},
"is_user_page": true,
"title": "Lily Smith",
"subtitle": "Photographer",
"about": [
    {
        "icon": "",
        "label": "Austin, TX"
    }
],
"photos": [
    {
        "position": 2,
        "description": "I love hiking",
        "photo": "/9j/2wCEAAgGBg....CEAAgGBg" <- (The rest of the binary data)
    }
]
}
```

OPTION B (Separating Concern)

The same JSON response, but instead of image data, using it's id.
Then getting it just the data through another request, but esencially making the front end handle two or more request to server.

Comment: Send the url? Especially if it’s a large image

Comment: agreed. I would only put the path to the image in the json. where is your image stored?